# How to filer what is shown in my view according to the content of one of the content fields?

Tags: drupal, view

I would like to know **how to filter view (block) according to content of one of my fields in that view.**

E.g. I have added to my block view a field called **Car description**, which contains a text with something like "This car is convertible and the best on the market." etc.

Now, I want in filers section set up a condition to show just that content which contains in the field Car description a word **convertible**.

I was wondering that if this is not possible, I can maybe create a custom field which will contain a PHP code with condition if else, so the result of this custom field could be 0 or 1 and then the filter could check it better.

However, I think that filter is applied before any of the fields are populated, but maybe I am wrong.

How to solve this problem? Did anyone dealt with similar situation?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use views filters.

In filter settings you can specify properties of that filter. For example you can check field for containing word 'convertible'.

However for your case I would use taxonomy. 'Convertible' word is a good candidate for taxonomy term.